# Openstack API - Difference between Dynamic Large Objects (DLO) & Static Large Objects (SLO)

Tags: openstack, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

I want to upload large objects to my objectstorage with the openstack API.
I found out that I can do that with the Large Objects.
In the API are two different objects discribed, the Static Large Objects (SLO) and the Dynamic Large Objects (DLO). For both I need to upload all of the parts and then a manifest, which holds the references to these parts.

Now my question is: what is the difference between these two? And which should I use? My files don't change their size. There are uploaded once, and then they are usually NOT changed. So I would suppose to use SLO?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from Oracle: [Using Oracle Storage Cloud Service](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/storagecs_common/CSSTO/GUID-67CFD2EC-4822-40F1-88F1-7599D0E7FC0A.htm)

The differences between these two is that SLO's Manifest file contains all contailer/file names of the segments. The segments can be at different locations. So it's called *static* because all files are initial uploaded and don't change.

The Manifest-file for the DLO's is empty. All segments must be in  the same container as the manifest-file is. This file determines dynamically the parts of the large object to be downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

> I've written a blog post on Object Storage manifests for the Bluemix service @ http://blog.ibmjstart.net/2016/04/14/e-pluribus-unum-creating-openstack-manifest-objects-in-ibm-bluemix-object-storage/ that may also help shed more light on their usefulness.

Excerpt:

- **Static Large Objects** (SLO) – Relies on a user provided manifest file. Advantageous for use cases when the developer wants to “mashup” objects from multiple containers and reference them in a self-generated manifest file.  This gives you immediate access to the concatenated object after the manifest is accepted. Uploading segments into separate containers provides the opportunity for improved concurrent upload speeds. On the downside, the concatenated object’s definition is frozen until the manifest is replaced.
- **Dynamic Large Objects** (DLO) – Relies on a container-listing zero-byte manifest file. Advantageous for use cases when the developer might add/remove segments from the manifest (e.g. objects from the container) at any time.  A few disadvantages include reliance on eventual consistent container listings which means there may be some delay before access to the full concatenated object is available.  There is also a requirement for all segments to be in a single container, which can limit concurrent upload speeds.

Based on your use case, I would agree that SLO probably makes the most sense.